# Burial Pod- Kosher?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, trees

So I just saw [this](http://distractify.com/pinar/human-now-tree-later/?ts_pid=2) on Facebook [warning: some links at the bottom of the page contain imagery which is not tzanua]

In short, this mentions a concept in which the body of the deceased is put into a pod which is then attached to the roots of a sapling. The nutrients from the remains feed the tree.

Now I'm sure that this would invoke issues of ohel, but otherwise, is this idea problematic?

Comment: How is this distinct from just planting a tree on top a grave?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, have you looked at the article? It certainly interferes with minhag, but I'm not sure of where it stands halachically.

Comment: I read the article and fail to see the problem. Only in Israel is there a custom to bury someone sans casket. Otherwise, I fail to see how it interferes with minhag as you insist it does. What minhag precludes this?

Comment: The link you provided either does not work anymore or is the wrong link.